# Intstalling Android Studio on 64-bit version of Lubuntu fails installing some 32-bit libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, installation

[Install Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#64bit-libs) says:

> If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:
>
> ```sh
> sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
> lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
> ```

See screenshot:
[image]

The `apt-get install` fails:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libc6:i386
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5:i386
E: Unable to locate package libstdc++6:i386
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libstdc++6'
E: Unable to locate package libbz2-1.0:i386
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libbz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libbz2-1.0'
```

Version info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:        19.10
Codename:       eoan

$ uname -a
Linux frozen 5.3.0-18-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 8 20:14:06 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I have reported this as a [documentation bug to Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143831779).

Answer (score 33):

I had also the same issue but this is how i solved mine. Installing 32-bit packages on 64-bit Linux needs you to enable or give instructions to the OS by telling it to allow installation of 32-bit packages/dependencies. In most cases when you install 64-bit Linux it will only have the 64-bit architecture configured. So its upon you to add 32-bit configuration.

First verify the architectures configured in your system;

```
sudo dpkg --print-architecture         //amd64
```

Second look for any other foreign architectures

```
sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures      //response should be nothing
```

Now proceed to add 32-bit architecture

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Verify 32-bit is added

```
sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures      //i386
```

Then update your packages

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install your 32-bit packages

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

Not addressing the `apt-get install` fails but gets Android Studio installed. [Snapcraft -- The app store for Linux](https://snapcraft.io/) has [How to install Android Studio
on Ubuntu](https://snapcraft.io/install/android-studio/ubuntu) which says for Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo):

```
$ sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

Answer (score -1):

If your using ubuntu you can just go to Ubuntu Software and download it from there without having to use terminal

Comment: What is the " it " ?

Comment: You can download android studio

Comment: lubuntu>Application Menu>System Tools>Muon Package Manager>Search>[android studio] produces a blank list.